# select option error on server side, but runs on client side

Tags: php, jquery

I have selection box and it has values and **[client example](http://jsfiddle.net/marafee1243/NLGPT/)**

and i have server code as below

```
  <select name="customer_id" id="customer_id">
<?php get_customer_list_options(); ?>
  </select> | 
  <input id="customer_name_from_sel" type="text" />
```

and below jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#customer_id").bind('change', function() {
        var k = $("#customer_id option:selected").attr("title");
        $("#customer_name_from_sel").val(k);
    });

});​

</script>
```

and function code

```
function get_customer_list_options() {
    $fquery39 = mysql_query("select User_ID, First_Name, Email_ID from customers");

    while($r39 = mysql_fetch_row($fquery39)) {
        echo "<option value='$r39[0]' title='$r39[1]' >$r39[2]</option>";
    }

}
```

Now when i run the code from jsfiddle, runs perfectly, while on server page, its not working out.
And i have already working jquery libraries are good.. in perfect state.

**the value attr `title` is not displayed on text `customer_name_from_sel`**

Below is the image output of HTML code.

[image]

Error image

[image]

Comment: What is not working? are you getting any errors? did you check your error logs? Did you turn on php error reporting?

Comment: Yes! php and mysql errors are `on`. the value attr `title` is not displayed on text `customer_name_from_sel`

Comment: Do you seriously use a different variable name for each result?!

Comment: @ThiefMaster I belive for `select` element will have only `name` for it, not for `<option>` elements. for that `<option>` element i gave a `title` as attribute and its coming from `database` dynamically

Comment: I'm talking about `$fquery39` and `$r39`

Comment: @ThiefMaster Yes, all has different variable for each and every functions

Comment: Did you check your HTML output to make sure the TITLE is actually set?

Comment: @AndrewR Yes!, it showing perfect output, and i will attach a image of that too.

Comment: Can we get a URL for the failing version? I wonder if there's not a JavaScript error that's preventing the code from executing.

Comment: can you show us the console image in google chrome and what the error if any.

Comment: I agree with @SetSailMedia about the possibility of a JS error. Is there anything under your 'Console' tab that shows an error? You don't have multiple elements with the customer_id tag do you?

Comment: @MohammedUzairAhmed Yes i got an error in console, it showing `Uncaught SyntaxError`

Comment: if there are other .js files you've linked in, or other JS code that executes before your `<select>` script, and that code contains an error, it could prevent your `<select>` script from ever executing. You can use the FireBug addon specifically looking at the Console Log or the Web Developer addon using Error Console's Errors tab to see what JavaScript errors are thrown (if any). Feel pretty strongly this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to test if   `$("#customer_id option:selected")` gets the correct element. If not,you can use `selectedIndex` to get the selected option.